# Angular 2 how to implement two way binding for level 2 child?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

An object is a property of parent component

`const public object = {value1: 'test1'};`

And it's used as a property for child component

`<app-child [(obj)]="object"></app-child>`

the child component itself has other child that takes `value1` field as a property

`<app-child-2 [(value)]="obj.value1"></app-child-2>`

The question is, can I use `[(value)]` for the second child or the only way how I can set up two way binding from the parent to the second child is't

`<app-child-2 [value]="obj.value1" (valueChange)="updateObjectFun()"></app-child-2>`

where `updateObjectFun` will set emit objectChange Output.

Comment: Have you tried `ngModel` ?

Comment: you should use [(ngModel)] and not [(propertyName)]

Comment: app-child is the parent of appchild2 right? Then app-child2 should emit to app-child which inturn will emit to parent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the two-way binding syntax if your child component has the correct 'interface'. So, for eg, if your second child component has an input binding of `value` and an output binding of `valueChange` then you can use the two-way binding syntax: `[(value)]="obj.value1"`.

The two-way binding syntax is the exact equivalent of:

```
[value]="obj.value1" (valueChange)="obj.value1=$event"
```

where `$event` is the object emitted from the valueChange output property of your component. If you have control over the interface of your component (i.e. you can create whatever properties you want), then feel free to take advantage of the two way binding syntax.

`ngModel` is only necessary for situations where you don't have control of the interface of the component you're binding to, and as such can't use the two way binding syntax shortcut.

*(The above statement is not completely true since ngModel also serves an extra purpose when dealing with template-driven forms, but for your use case, that's not a concern).*

Comment: Any idea why this example does not work? https://angular-yqhzlp.stackblitz.io

Comment: In the previous example, clicking the top button would update all three, but clicking the bottom button only updated its immediate parent. In this new example, I changed the hierarchy to use an EventEmitter at the top, and at the bottom, I have a BehaviorSubject. Now clicking either button updates all three bindings. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wgggtd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent.component.ts

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the problem here. The question isn't about how to achieve two-way binding (which your answer covers), it's about what happens when you try to do that through 2 layers of nested components. I think the author of the question is correct in that you have to separate out the inputs and outputs in the middle layer template to make this propagate correctly all the way out.